# How to extract and create new columns from specific match

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a column **bike_name** and I want to know the easiest way to split it into **year** and **CC**.

**CC** should contain the numeric data attached before the word *cc*. In some cases, where cc is not available, it should remain blank.

While **year** contains just the year in the last word.

```
TVS Star City Plus Dual Tone 110cc 2018
Royal Enfield Classic 350cc 2017
Triumph Daytona 675R 2013
TVS Apache RTR 180cc 2017
Yamaha FZ S V 2.0 150cc-Ltd. Edition 2018
Yamaha FZs 150cc 2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract them separately: `year` is the last 4 characters, `CC` is via a regex:

```
df["year"] = df.bike_name.str[-4:]

df["CC"] = df.bike_name.str.extract(r"(\d+)cc").fillna("")
```

where [regex](https://regex101.com/r/YXbs1O/1) is looking for sequence of digits followed literally by `"cc"` and in case of no match, it will give `NaN`s; so we fill them with empty string,

to get

```
                                   bike_name  year   CC
0    TVS Star City Plus Dual Tone 110cc 2018  2018  110
1           Royal Enfield Classic 350cc 2017  2017  350
2                  Triumph Daytona 675R 2013  2013
3                  TVS Apache RTR 180cc 2017  2017  180
4  Yamaha FZ S V 2.0 150cc-Ltd. Edition 2018  2018  150
5                      Yamaha FZs 150cc 2015  2015  150
```

---

If not only extraction but also removal is needed:

```
df.bike_name = (df.bike_name.str[:-4]
                  .str.replace(r"\d+cc", "", regex=True)
                  .str.rstrip())
```

where first line removes *year*, second line removes the *cc* parts and lastly we `r`ight `strip` all the rows if space at the end is unwanted,

to get

```
>>> df

                     bike_name  year   CC
0      TVS Star City Plus Dual  2018  110
1            Royal Enfield Cla  2017  350
2              Triumph Daytona  2013
3                   TVS Apache  2017  180
4  Yamaha FZ S V 2.0 -Ltd. Edi  2018  150
5                       Yamaha  2015  150
```

Comment: Great. How do I remove year and cc from the original bike name as well?

Comment: @sais, edited the answer for removing them, hope it helps.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks